# splitting digits of an integer into a vector, rotating them, then converting back to an integer

Tags: c++, vector

My goal is to take an integer, my example is 197, check if it's prime, if it is prime, rotate the digits and check primality until I get back to 197, otherwise break the look.  I plan on looping through a ton of numbers to do this.

My first method used is myPow.  It is used to take long int powers (like 2^20).

```
long myPow(long x, long p) {
    if (p == 0) { return 1; }
    if (p == 1){ return x; }
    return x * myPow(x, p - 1);
}
```

This function counts the number of digits.

```
int numdigits(long r){
    unsigned int number_of_digits = 0;

    do {
        ++number_of_digits;
        r /= 10;
    } while (r);
    return number_of_digits;
}
```

This checks for primality.

```
bool isPrime(unsigned long long n) {
if (n <= 3) {
    return n > 1;
}

if (n % 2 == 0 || n % 3 == 0) {
    return false;
}

for (unsigned long long i = 5; i * i <= n; i += 6) {
    if (n % i == 0 || n % (i + 2) == 0) {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
}
```

This takes an integer and splits the digits into a vector 
(integer 123 -> vector(1,2,3))

```
vector<int> digits(int x){
    vector<int> myvec;
    while (x >= 10){
        myvec.push_back(x % 10);
        x = x / 10; 
}

    myvec.push_back(x);
    reverse(myvec.begin(), myvec.end());
    return myvec;
}
```

This is the main class.
It loops through each integer, checks if it is prime.  If it is prime, I use k to compare it to i, because eventually it will rotate to itself and the while look will finish. I set the flag to be true, it is set to false when a different rotation of the number fails to be prime and after the loop finishes, it will not count the integer.
I create the vector mydigs to store the digits, let h = the number of digits.  I assign a = h to avoid computing numdigits(i) in the while loop.

This is where i think things are wrong.  I rotate once and I assign k to be the integer.  I check if that is prime, if not, break and set flag to false.  Otherwise it will continue to loop and keep rotating.  The problem is that when I run this for just 197, which I know would be prime every time I rotate the integer, I end up failing because when I rotate a second time I get the wrong number.  Which is why I have it outputting k, just to see why things are wrong.

What output should be:

971,
719,
1

Output I get:

971, 
1690,  **< -- this I don't understand.**
0,

```
int main(){
unsigned t0 = clock();
int totalcircle = 0;
for (int i = 197; i < 198; i += 2){
    if (isPrime(i)){
        long k = 0;
        bool flag = true;
        vector<int> mydigs = digits(i);
        int h = numdigits(i); 
        int a;
        while (i != k){
            a = h;
            rotate(mydigs.begin(), mydigs.begin()+1, mydigs.end());
            for (vector<int>::iterator it = mydigs.begin(); it !=  mydigs.end(); ++it){
                k += (*it) * myPow(10, a - 1);
                a--;
            }

            std::cout << k << std::endl;
            if (!isPrime(k)){
                flag = false;
                break;
            }

        }
        if (flag){
            std::cout << i << endl;
            totalcircle++;
        }
    }

}

std::cout << totalcircle << endl;
unsigned elapsed = clock() - t0;
std::cout << "Elapsed time: " << elapsed << endl;
std::system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You keep adding on to `k` in the inner loop. `1690 == 971 + 719`

Comment: ah!  That fixed it.  Thank you sir.  Just set k = 0; above a=h; and it fixed the problem.  (Although, it still runs for 47 s, there's probably a more efficient way to do this).

Comment: You can use arithmetic to rotate, no need for a vector of digits. `rotated = n/10 + (n % 10)*pow(10, h-1)`

Comment: Yeah, I figured there was an easier way.  I just started learning C++ a week ago, so I guess getting used to using vectors is a bonus learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::rotate` in place of your function as follows

```
#include <iostream>     
#include <algorithm>    
#include <vector>      
int main () {
  std::vector<int> myvector={1,9,7};
  std::rotate(myvector.begin(),myvector.end()-1,  myvector.end());
  std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for ( auto &x : myvector)
     std::cout<<x;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I wish I could give you and Igor votes, but I am new here and I need 15 rep.

Comment: Uh, `std::rotate` *is* what the OP uses, as far as I can tell.